# How do I loop over items in a Javascript array with a for loop, executing each item individually before moving onto the next (until completed)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

The array I tried looping over is called `commands` in the object below.  I've given it a series of commands that I've defined in the functions below it.  And my for loop is in the bottom function called `commandsArray()`.  I try calling the `commandsArray()` in the program to execute the loop over the array, but it's not working.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I would definitely like to use a for-loop here and try to make that work if possible.  I'm new to Javascript.

```
     var myRover = {
     position: [[0],[0]],
     direction: 'N',
     roverDirections: ['N', 'E', 'S', 'W'],
     marsGrid: [[0], [0]],
     obstacles: [],
     commands: ['f','f', 'f', 'r', 'f', 'f', 'l', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'b', 'b']
    };

    // MOVE FORWARD & BACKWARD COMMANDS

    function move(command) {


    if (command === 'f') {   //FORWARD

    switch(myRover.direction) {
    case 'N':
      myRover.position[0]++;
      break;
    case 'E':
      myRover.position[1]++;
      break;
    case 'S':
      myRover.position[0]--;
      break;
    case 'W':
      myRover.position[1]--;
      break;
      }
    }

    else if (command === 'b') {  //BACKWARD

        switch(myRover.direction) {
      case 'N':
        myRover.position[0]--;
        break;
      case 'E':
        myRover.position[1]--;
        break;
      case 'S':
        myRover.position[0]++;
        break;
      case 'W':
        myRover.position[1]++;
        break;

        }
       }
       return myRover.position;
      }



    // TURN COMMANDS

    function turn(command){

    if (command === 'l') {   //TURNING LEFT

      switch (myRover.direction) {
        case 'N':
        myRover.direction = 'W';
        break;
        case 'E':
        myRover.direction = 'N';
        break;
        case 'S':
        myRover.direction = 'E';
        break;
        case 'W':
        myRover.direction = 'S';
        break;
      }
    }

    if (command === "r") {    //TURNING RIGHT
      switch (myRover.direction) {
        case 'N':
        myRover.direction = 'E';
        break;
        case 'E':
        myRover.direction = 'S';
        break;
        case 'S':
        myRover.direction = 'W';
        break;
        case 'W':
        myRover.direction = 'N';
        break;
    }
}
     return myRover.direction;



}





    // Executing on a Series of Commands From the Commands Array

    function commandsArray() {


    var commandsLength = myRover.commands.length;
    for (var i = 0; i <= commandsLength; i++) {
        if (commandsLength[i] === 'f') {
          move('f');
        }

        else if (commandsLength[i] === 'b') {
          move('b');
        }

        if (commandsLength[i] === 'r') {
          turn('r');
        }
        else if (commandsLength[i] === 'l') {
          turn('l');
        }

      return myRover.position;
    }
```

Comment: what does "not working" mean?  Can you share the error message?

Comment: "it's not working" doesn't describe what is happening. Be specific!

Comment: `but it's not working` in what way. What do you expect? What do you observe? Are there errors in the console

Comment: `return myRover.position;` looks to be *inside* the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this block of code:

```
function commandsArray() {

    var commandsLength = myRover.commands.length;
    for (var i = 0; i <= commandsLength; i++) {
        if (commandsLength[i] === 'f') {
          move('f');
        }

        else if (commandsLength[i] === 'b') {
          move('b');
        }

        if (commandsLength[i] === 'r') {
          turn('r');
        }
        else if (commandsLength[i] === 'l') {
          turn('l');
        }

      return myRover.position;
    }
}
```

It looks like `return myRover.position` is inside the `for` loop.  And `myRover.commands` contains the array (not `commandsLength`). Try this instead:

```
function commandsArray() {

    var commandsLength = myRover.commands.length;
    for (var i = 0; i <= commandsLength; i++) {
        if (myRover.commands[i] === 'f') {
          move('f');
        }

        else if (myRover.commands[i] === 'b') {
          move('b');
        }

        if (myRover.commands[i] === 'r') {
          turn('r');
        }
        else if (myRover.commands[i] === 'l') {
          turn('l');
        }
    }
    return myRover.position;
}
```

Or better yet:

```
function commandsArray() {
    const turns = ['l', 'r'];
    myRover.commands.forEach(command => {
       if (turns.includes(command)) {
           turn(command);
       } else {
           move(command);
       }
    });
    return myRover.position;
}
```

Comment: I didn't receive any error messages, but rather in calling the commandsArray() function, the rover wouldn't actually move on the grid.

Comment: It worked!  I tweaked it according to your second suggestion, and the function worked.  Thank you so much.  These moments are very encouraging and keep me going.  Thank you thank you thank you.

Comment: Is it even worth creating the commandsLength variable in this case?